# Assert not parsable number

Tags: javascript, chai

How can I assert the keys of an object are not parsed as numbers?
Basically both `3` and `"3"` should raise an error.

I'm using [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/api/assert/) and this is what I have done so far:

```js
it("shouldn't have numeric keys", () => {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => chai.assert.isNotNumber(key));  // where key is "3"
});
```

This doesn't raise an error if the key is `"3"`.
Thank you.

By the way, I need this to guarantee the object property order accordingly to [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Object property names cannot be numbers. They can only be strings or Symbol instances. In particular, `Object.keys()` always returns an array of strings.

Comment: So, how can I assert `"3"` is not a valid key? Should I use parseInt or Chai has got something more convenient?

Comment: Well, as far as JavaScript is concerned there's nothing wrong with the string `"3"` as a property name. You could test for `isNaN(+key)` if for some reason your application doesn't like numeric property names.

Comment: As to the last statement in the question, relying on property creation order in general is a fragile coding practice. Yes, the order is standardized, but it's based on the "life experience" of each individual object and it's not really under direct control of the application code.

Comment: It sounds like you need to check if it is a number, or a string that parses to a number.  You could try converting it and testing if the result is a number, or apply a RegEx test.

Comment: @scunliffe thank you, Pointy solution's works already really well. That was the answer for me.